# Grunt - DSS Plugin

Tags: sass, gruntjs, kss

I'm trying to get this Grunt plugin to work:

https://npmjs.org/package/dss

This documentation plugin ironically seems to be lacking proper documentation. Can someone help me out by giving me an example of something that worked for them. The main thing that's screwing me up is the "your_target" property. Not sure what's suppose to go in there.

Say I have a SASS file in the following path from the root directory:

**sass/main.scss**

What would my ouput be by default? And where would it output to? Also what format does it ouput to?

```
grunt.initConfig({
    DSS: {
        options: {
        // Task-specific options go here.
        },
        your_target: {
        // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
        },
    },
})
```

Is "**your_target**" property the path to my sass file or the path to the documentation file I'm trying to create? Would it be defined like this?

```
...
your_target: {
    // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
    sass: "sass/main.scss"
},
...
```

I don't know what the property name should be. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
dss: {
    docs: {
       options: {
       },
       files: {
           'api/': 'css/**/*.{css,scss,sass,less,styl}'
       }
    }
}
```